# SSRS using a sessionID

Tags: php, asp.net, reporting-services, mysqli

Can you use a Stored session variable to call a SSRS 
For example a $_SESSION['UserId'] To call a SSRS in Aspx ? Thanks for any help you can provide

Comment: Are you needing to pass the Session variable as a parameter into your report? And is this stored in a cookie?

Comment: I need to use say a Unique identifier to look where the report will pull from like a score or something

Comment: OK so is the identifier stored in the cookies collection for access in your server side code? If so, you should just be able to include the value as a named parameter in your report parameter values collection before requesting the report. Are you using the asp.net report viewer control?

Comment: I am using a report viewer control you type the UserId and it then shows you the report i wanna skip this step and do it automatically from the UserId Ethier from the database or from the cookie ive stored

Comment: Ok so can you share the code you have wired up so far to make the report request taking that userId input?

Answer (score 0):

https://ssrsphp.codeplex.com/ found my answer here basically calls the report in php which i use a paramater of the session ID to call the report